# having children take up same height as parent and proportional widths

Tags: html, css

I am working to make a table with divs, but the cells need to contain a more complex structure.  In a sense, each cell cell represents an hour, it will need to be split up into half hour and quarter hour segments.

```
<!-- a Cell example -->
<div class="cell hour">
   <div class="half-hour">
     <div class="quarter-hour"></div>
     <div class="quarter-hour"></div>
   </div>
   <div class="half-hour">
     <div class="quarter-hour"></div>
     <div class="quarter-hour"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

seems to be a good way to represent my structure.

**There are 2 things I want to be able to do:**  Make it so that pending a flag, will adjust the hover class.  Example:

```
options = ['hour','hh','qh']

if (hour) apply onHover/onClick to hour blocks.
if (hh) apply onHover/onClick to halfhour blocks.
if (qh) apply onHover/onClick to qh blocks.
```

The other thing I want to be able to do is have the blocks take up the proportional amount of space of its parent.  Example:  each of the HH will take up 50% of the hour, and the 2 QH will each take up 50% of their parent.  *It seems that my `half-hour` and `quarter-hour` blocks have no defined shape as of yet.

Im working on making a small scheduler for the week, allowing them to toggle blocks and then when they save, parse based on the 'selected' class

Here is a fiddle I have been working with: https://jsfiddle.net/dybsrzg3/

While i am using dart, I know in JQUERY i could do something like attach the hover and click handlers to the dom and apply it to the selection by way of:

```
$("document").on("hover","selection", function(){ ... });
$("document").on("click","selection", function(){ ... });
```

as long as `selection` is added to the dom elements which are selectable.

Comment: Updated the jsfiddle so that all half-hour and quarter-hour blocks are visible (the second part of your question). Note the comments in the css with what to change if you want the height of sub elements to take up the full height of the cell. 

https://jsfiddle.net/dybsrzg3/2/

I'm not positive what you mean by the first part of your question. Do you mean you want some external variable (such a combobox selection) determining whether clicking/hovering on a cell is interacting with the full hour, hh or qh?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The empty cells caught off guard since they need some height to be visible, so I added the height to them as well as relative positioning and 50% width of their parent as well as a border to see the edges of the quarter hours.

Customize as needed.

```
.hour{
    background-color:grey;
    position:relative;
}
.half-hour{
    background-color: teal;
    display:inline-block;
    float: left;
    width:50%;
    height: 100%;
}
.quarter-hour{
    background-color:pink;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    display:inline-block;
    float: left;
    width:calc(50% - 2px);
    height: 100%;
}

.table{
    display: table-cell;
}
.row {
    display:table-row;
}
.cell, .row-header, .column-header {
    display:table-cell;
}
.cell {
    border: solid 1px black;
    height: 1px;
    width: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.column-header{
    text-align:center;
}
.cell:hover{
    background-color: cyan;
}
```

Comment: Is it possible for you to modify the fiddle so i can see it in action?  I want to inspect it and see whats going on in order to learn a bit more and understand the concept  **update:  that CSS is just a copy-paste of the jsfiddle css**

Comment: It seems like if i wanted to make the quarter hour just a bit wider, it seems that if i remove `calc(50% - 2pm)` to just be `50%` it seems that it doesnt set the width correctly?

Comment: The "-2px" is to eliminate the extra space generated by the border. You can eliminate the border and then use 50% width.